# C# async for infinite loops

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have a process that connects to a host and infinitely checks if there is new data to process.

My application has close to 500 threads and each thread runs in an infinite loop..

Here's the code :

```
for(i=1; i<=500; i++)
{
   Thread instanceCaller = new Thread(new ThreadStart(infiniteProcess));
   instanceCaller.Start();
}
```

Is there a better way to write this code using C# async. Also, will there be any performance improvements if we use async instead of threadstart.

---

I want to clarify why I would like to create 500 threads and having a thread pool doesn't work for me.

Basically, each of this thread opens a dedicated socket connection to the host. The host sends a message to this socket which is then routed to the appropriate destination (configured in the DB). The destination could be a hardware device (printer etc., ) or some other device.

We cannot create thread pools because, each of this thread is very active and continuously receives messages from the host and processes them. The overhead of loading and unloading threads from the thread pool is inefficient.

My original application created using threads works well.. But I would like to see if there is any way we can improve the efficiency by taking advantage of new features in C# 5.0.

Comment: Why would you need 500 threads like this?

Comment: you would get a improvement if you would use something like a worker-queue and just a handfull of Threads ....

Comment: Your performance hits are just due to the sheer number of threads and all in a loop, I can't see why this would be the only option available to you, can you not use events to take place of the threads if they are acting in a listener capacity?

Comment: Reminds me of some throwaway user that wanted to know how to create 500 threads for a spamming tool.

Comment: @user1071777 - you mean some user wit a name like user1071776 ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman The difference is that they have 1 rep.

Comment: @crashmstr - I've edited the question to answer your query

Comment: @CarstenKönig These threads are hyper-active... There is no downtime. So, I wouldn't think there would be any performance gains if I use a worker queue.

Comment: @Wobbles I've edited the question to address your concerns..  I'm all open to hear any suggestions for the scenario i've mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get into the hundreds of threads you should consider replacing blocking by asynchronous IO and asynchronous waiting. **Many threads cause high memory usage and OS scheduling overhead.**

**Try to remove the calls that block the longest first. Apply the 80-20 principle. You don't have to go all async.**

That said the overheads associated with this many threads are generally overestimated. Your code will *not* suddenly become 2x faster if you go all async. Async really only changes the way an operation is started and ended. The operation itself (the IO or the wait) is not accelerated at all.

Also, async does not add capacity. Your CPUs don't become faster, the database cannot handle more operations and the network has a fixed throughput as well. Async IO is really about saving memory and scheduling overhead.

You will not hit OS limits with 500 threads. I recently created 100,000 threads on my machine using testlimits.exe without much trouble. The limits are really high.

Comment: And was  that 100K _managed_ threads? Because that would take 100 GB. Committed memory.

Comment: @HenkHolterman unmanaged. For managed, memory is the limiting factor. I tried to convey that there are no relevant OS limits. I created 30k managed thread with 256k stack size, though. No big deal. I try to dispel the myth that having many threads is an untenable situation.

Comment: The main tag here is [C#]. Having many threads is an untenable situation, don't dispel that.

Comment: @usr I understand your suggestions and I think you're right. I shouldn't try to go all async..